# How can I initiate a file transfer between two remote VMs on Google Cloud using nodejs?

Tags: shell, node.js, gcp

I need to automate a process such that when a nodejs function is fired a remote source sends certain files to a remote destination VM. I’ve been looking everywhere but can’t find any easy solution.

Comment: Can you add more context/info? Are you working in the cloud? 'a remote source' - remote from the NodeJS function? What are you actually trying to do? https://sketchplanations.com/the-xy-problem